Natural Deduction proof verification with identity
I'm trying to proof this
$$\forall y \exists x (f(x) = y) \wedge \forall y \exists x (g(x) = y) \vdash \forall y \exists x (f(g(x)) = y)$$
Using natural deduction. A way I found was
$\forall y \exists x (f(x) = y)$ (Premise)
$\forall y \exists x (g(x) = y)$ (Premise)
Let $y$ be an arbitrary element.
From $\forall y \exists x (g(x) = y)$, by universal instantiation, we get $\exists x (g(x) = y)$.
Assume $g(a) = y$ for some $a$.
From $\forall y \exists x (f(x) = y)$, by universal instantiation, we get $\exists x (f(x) = g(a))$.
Assume $f(b) = g(a)$ for some $b$.
Substitute $g(a)$ with $y$ (from the assumption $g(a) = y$), we get $f(b) = y$.
Since $g(a) = y$, we have $f(g(a)) = y$.
Therefore, $\exists x (f(g(x)) = y)$ (Existential introduction).
Since $y$ was arbitrary, $\forall y \exists x (f(g(x)) = y)$ (Universal generalization).
But I'm not sure this is a right way to this using natural deduction, mainly because existential elimination that does not follow van dalen way and its restrisctions

Can someone show me a way to do this following its restrisctions or explain me if the way I did is correct?
Thanks for attention

The step $f(b)=y$ and $g(a)=y$, therefore $f(g(a))=y$ seems not correct...

You have to follow the hint in the first answer: from $∀y∃x(f(x)=y)$ by $(\forall \text E)$ we have $∃x(f(x)=z)$ [used $z$ for clarity] and then assume for $(\exists \text E)$ $f(b)=z$ for some $b$.
Then re-use $b$ with second part of the premise to get: $∃x(g(x)=b)$ and then again for $(\exists \text E)$ you have $g(a)=b$ for some $a$.
Now, from $f(b)=z$ and $g(a)=b$ by equality: $f(g(a))=z$ and you can use $(\exists \text I)$ to derive: $\exists x (f(g(x))=z)$.
There are no more occurrences neither of $a$ nor of $b$ in the conclusion, and thus you can correctly close both $(\exists \text E)$'s discharging the temporary assumptions, having the desired: $\exists x (f(g(x))=z)$.
It seems tricky but it works... when you use $(\exists \text E)$ you start a sub-proof with a new assumption: in this case $f(b)=z$, and in that sub-proof, you use $(\exists \text E)$ again, opening a new sub-proof with assumption $g(a)=b$. Then derive $\exists x(f(g(x))=z)$.
In $\exists x(f(g(x))=z)$ there is neother $a$ nor$b$ either: thus it is used to close both sub-proofs by $(\exists \text E)$ discharging the corresponding assumptions and concluding with $\exists x(f(g(x))=z)$.
In array form:
$$
\begin{array}{|l}
~~1.~~\forall y \exists x (f(x)=y) \land \forall y \exists x (g(x)=y)\hspace{5ex}\text{Premise to which you have to apply} \land \text E \\
~~2.~~ \exists x (f(x)=z) \hspace{10ex} \forall \text E,1 \\\hline
\begin{array}{|l}
~~3.~~f(b)=z \hspace{10ex} \text{assumption for } \exists \text E,1 \\\hline
~~4.~~\exists x (g(x)=b) \hspace{10ex} \forall \text E,1 \\
\begin{array}{|l}
~~5.~~g(a)=b \hspace{10ex} \text{new assumption for second } \exists \text E,4 \\\hline
~~6.~~\exists x (f(g(x))=z) \hspace{10ex} \text{by identity and } \exists \text I,5 \\\hline
\end{array} \\
~~7.~~\exists x (f(g(x))=z) \hspace{10ex} \text{by } \exists \text E,4-6 \\\hline
\end{array} \\
~~8.~~\exists x (f(g(x))=z) \hspace{10ex} \text{by } \exists \text E,2-8 \\\hline
~~9.~~\forall y \exists x (f(g(x))=y) \hspace{10ex} \forall \text I,8 \\
\end{array} \\
$$

The core is to derive $g(a)=\color{navy}b, f(\color{navy}b)=z\vdash f(g(a))=z$ by the identity substitution rule (${=}\mathrm E$).
Taking $z$ as arbitrary, and $a,b$ as witnesses for the existentials in the premise, the $\exists$ and $\forall$ rules pad out the proof.
Let $\require{HTML}\def\D{\dfrac} \varphi:=\forall y~\exists x~(f(x)=y)\wedge\forall y~\exists x~(g(x)=y)$
$\qquad\D{\D{\varphi}{\D{\forall y~\exists x~(f(x)=y)}{\exists x~(f(x)=z)}{\forall\mathrm E}\hspace{-3.5ex}}{\wedge\mathrm E}~~\lower{3.5ex}{\D{\D{\varphi}{\D{\forall y~\exists x~(g(x)=y)}{\exists x~(g(x)=b)}{{\forall}\mathrm E}\hspace{-3.5ex}}{\wedge\mathrm E}~~\D{[g(a)=b]^2~[f(b)=z]^1}{\D{f(g(a))=z}{\exists x~f(g(x))=z)}{\exists\mathrm I}\hspace{-9ex}}{{=}\mathrm E}\hspace{-3.5ex}}{\exists x~(f(g(x))=z)}{\exists\mathrm E^{2}\hspace{-4ex}}}}{\D{\exists x~(f(g(x)=z)}{\forall y~\exists x~(f(g(x))=y)}{\forall\mathrm I}\hspace{-50ex}}{\exists\mathrm E^{1}}$

So, in the deduction tree, $f(b)=z$ will be at the same level of $\exists y(fx)=z)$ for example? but how can this be correct given the elimination rule? the hypoothesis and conclusion will be the same?

Can you draw the deduction tree? I'm not vizualizing this elimination

@Carinhalogoali In the deduction tree the conclusion derived from the assumption of $f(b)=z$ will be on the same level as the existential $\exists x~(f(x)=z)$ which "eliminates" (ie discharges) that assumption.

Let $y$ be an arbitrary element. Then $\exists b (f(b)=y)$. For $b$, $\exists a (g(a)=b)$. Therefore, $\exists a (f(g(a))=y)$.

This isn't the way for thid type of proof

@Carinhalogoali Could you tell me why?
